# Caching system outside the network

Tags: caching, networking, browser, proxy, lan

There is a caching policy for some organizations. for example, if you want to use Internet via their network, you need to set the cache proxy in your browser to be able to access the internet.

My question is that, what happens if you are **outside** the network and **leave** that automatic configuration setting part (i.e. "use automatic configuration script" part in GOOGLE CHROME) **as it was set** at the organization? Does your information **still** passes that proxy server? or is it automatically ignored when you are out of the organization's network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this configuration script is stored on a server inside your organization for ease of administration. This means that is not necessarily accessible when you bring your computer outside. However, the script may be cached locally and even have optional configurations depending on your location. It depends on what your network administrators have set up for you.

Also, the proxy server is normally a part of your organizations network, and accessible only from the inside, which means it will most likely not work when outside.

To switch your network settings depending on your location, you can use software like this: http://www.eusing.com/ipswitch/free_ip_switcher.htm